# React Query useQuery & Axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, fetch, react-query

I'm trying to create an API function with a help of React Query and Axios.
When I'm using useQuery with vanilla fetch function - it all works perfectly.

```
export const useGetDebts = async () => {
  const { families } = appStore.user;
  const res = useQuery("getDebts", async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/family/${families[0]}/debts`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${appStore.token ?? ""}`,
      },
    });
    const parsedBody: DebtsResponse = await res.json();
    return parsedBody;
  });
  return res;
};
```

But when I switch the vanilla fetch function to Axios - I get an error status of 500 (not sure if it comes from React Query or Axios).

```
export const useGetDebts = async () => {
  const { families } = appStore.user;
  const res = useQuery("getDebts", async () => {
    const res = await axiosInstance.get<DebtsResponse>(`/api/family/${families[0]}/debts`);
    return res.data;
  });
  return res;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any explanations/suggestions.

P.s. The axiosInstance works fine with the useMutation hook. So it only makes me more confused. =(

```
export const useGetDebt = () => (
  useMutation(async (id: number) => {
    const { families } = appStore.user;
    const res = await axiosInstance.get<DebtResponse>(`/api/family/${families[0]}/debts/${id}`);
    return res.data;
  })
);
```

P.s.s. I'm working with React Native if it's somehow relevant.

Answer (score 0):

react-query doesn't give you any 500 errors because react-query doesn't do any data fetching. It just takes the promise returned from the queryFn and manages the async state for you.

I'm not sure if the `fetch` code really works because it doesn't handle any errors. `fetch` does not transform erroneous status codes like 4xx or 5xx to a failed promise like `axios` does. You need to check `response.ok` for that:

```
 useQuery(['todos', todoId], async () => {
   const response = await fetch('/todos/' + todoId)
   if (!response.ok) {
     throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
   }
   return response.json()
 })
```

see [Usage with fetch and other clients that do not throw by default](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-functions#usage-with-fetch-and-other-clients-that-do-not-throw-by-default).

So my best guess is that the `fetch` example also gives you a 500 error code, but you are not forwarding that error to react-query.

Comment: The ```fetch``` works fine without 4xx or 5xx error, because I do receive the data object, which is not happening with Axios - there data is returned as undefined. You can change the URL to this https://freegeoip.app/json to check the results.

Comment: There are plenty of examples in the docs that use axios and public apis for data fetching. Maybe you can take one of those and work towards your code. Try replacing the axiosInstance with plain axios etc